# JAVA ERROR: Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.ArrayList;

Tags: java, casting, runtime

Can anyone help to explain why I got this runtime error for the code below?
(no solution is needed) Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

class GFG {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer>[] arr = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new Object[2];
    }
}
```

> Runtime Errors: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   [Ljava.util.ArrayList;    at GFG.main(File.java:5)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the API Specifications for the `[ClassCastException][1]`:

> Thrown to indicate that the code has
>   attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an
>   instance.

In your case, you are down-casting (casting `Object` to `ArrayList`). Every `ArrayList` is an `Object`, but not every `Object` is an `ArrayList`.

Generally, downcasting is not a good idea. You should avoid it. If you use it, you better include a check using `instanceof`.

```
Object o = new ArrayList<>();
if (o instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) o;
}
```

Comment: But Object class is a super class to each class. No?

Comment: @Abhishek, yes.

Comment: Hi @HarshalParekh, thanks for your response. My question was more about the reason of runtim errors. I saw some openJDK code use "E[] tmp = (E[])new Object[input.length]; ". I don't understand why other code works fine but my code doesn't. (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java)

Comment: What you have posted is generics. It’s not the same as your code, hence the exception.